# Finding max number form the input list

Tags: python, numbers, max

I am trying to find maximum number from the list but not able to find the logical error in the code

```
def find_max(numbers):
    data = numbers.split(" ")
    maximum = data[0]
    for number in data:
        if number > maximum:
            maximum = number
        return maximum


number = input("Enter number with space:")
answer = find_max(number)
print(answer)
```

Comment: what data type do you think `data[0]` is?

Comment: I was expecting it to be int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `max` here.
The reason why your code doesn't work is because you did not convert the numbers to integes, they are still strings in your script.

The classical way:

```
def find_max(numbers):

    # if the list is empty return nothing
    if len(numbers) <= 0:
        return None

    # iterate to find the maximum
    maximum = numbers[0]
    for number in numbers:
        if number > maximum:
            maximum = number

    return maximum


numbers = input("Enter numbers with space:")

# transform the numbers string into a list of strings
numbers = numbers.split(" ")

# prepare numbers by converting them into integers
integers = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    number_as_integer = int(numbers[i])
    integers.append(number_as_integer)

# find the max
answer = find_max(integers)
print(answer)
```

The enhanced way:

```
def find_max(numbers):
    return max(map(int, numbers.split(" ")))


number = input("Enter numbers with space:")
answer = find_max(number)
print(answer)
```

Comment: it might also help a new user to show them how it is done with a `for-loop` so that they can learn the logic behind it, as opposed to just throwing a `map` at them which might be confusing

Comment: @aws_apprentice it really depends on the objectives of the OP. But in general you are right, a novice should be able to compute a max without special functions, and and the same time he/she should also learn about these specials from Python.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I added also a more comprehensive / classical way

Comment: I convert the string to integer but still there is logical error. Can you point out?
I added this line in the fucntion

data1 = numbers.split(" ")
data = list(map(int, data1))

Comment: @hurat your `return maximum` is indented too much, it's in the forloop, hence at the first iteration of the forloop it will return the first `maximum`, which in your case is `data[0]`

Answer (score 3):

The return statement is inside the for, so this will return always the first number entered. Also, you are comparing strings with int. Try this (is a solution of your own code, there are better ways to do this)

```
def find_max(numbers):
    data = numbers.split(" ")
    maximum = int(data[0])
    for number in data:
        if int(number) > maximum:
            maximum = int(number)
    return maximum


number = input("Enter number with space:")
answer = find_max(number)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your

```
data = numbers.split(" ")
```

to

```
data = map(int, numbers.split(" "))
```

to make it work. For Python 3 you need

```
data = list(map(int, numbers.split(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

found the problem.
There were two problems.
1) That I need to convert string into int
2) my return function should have been below the for loop.
Here is the corrected code

```
def find_max(numbers):
    data1 = numbers.split(" ")
    data = list(map(int, data1))
    maximum = data[0]
    for number in data:
        if number > maximum:
            maximum = number
    return maximum


number = input("Enter number with space:")
answer = find_max(number)
print(answer)
```

Comment: Thank you guys.I appreciate it